# Publish post on Facebook Page using Graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, post

I'm trying to post a link with a message on my facebook page as the facebook page itself. I'm following the instructions given in the following link.

https://coderwall.com/p/6zs3gw/using-facebook-s-api-to-post-to-my-organization-s-fb-page-from-my-organization-s-website

I following the steps given in the above webpage to generate a page_access_token that never expires and doing a POST request to graph API to publish a post.

In the link CURL command is being used but I'm trying to use POST request with jQuery $ajax()method. When ever i make the POST ajax request I get the following 403 error message.

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/pageid/feed 403 ()
Not able to send message
```

Javascript Code..

```
        var req = {
            access_token:"page_access_token",
            message:"posting with page token",
            link:"http://www.google.com"
        }

        $.ajax({
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/pageid/feed',
        type: 'post',
        data: JSON.stringify(req),
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },

        error: function() {
            console.log("Not able to send message");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Any reason you are not simply using the JS SDK?

Comment: You’re pretending that you are sending the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but what you actually send is JSON – that doesn’t match.